# Creating a custom jQuery plugin: "pluginName is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

When I call to the plugin in the document ready, It is working fine. But when I do the same thing in the button click event I am getting an error 
**TypeError: jQuery(...).coreFrame is not a function**

Anyone having any idea about this ? thanx in advance.

**My plugin**

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.coreFrame = function(dataObject, templateName) {

        if (dataObject.Error.Status == 200){
            var source   = $("#"+templateName).html();
            var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
            var actualTemplate    = template(dataObject);

            return $(this).html(actualTemplate);
        }else{  
            var notificationArray ={};
            notificationArray["type"]= "info-box-red";
            notificationArray["message"]= notificationDetails[0].msg;


            var source   = $("#error_template").html();
            var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
            var actualTemplate    = template(notificationArray);

            return $(this).html(actualTemplate);
        }   
    }

}(jQuery));




$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#station-list-container").coreFrame(obj ,list_template);
  **It's working like this.** 

  $("button").on("click",function(){
    $("#station-list-container").coreFrame(obj ,list_template);
    **It's NOT woking.** 
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in a [fiddle](http://jsbin.com) ?

Comment: we need to see the HTML of the page, that error means that when you call coreFrame the plugin has not been loaded yet.

Comment: Hmmm ok give me a second

Comment: is your snippet correct? you have an extra `function()` in the code

Comment: @ Fabrizio Calderan Sorry, Its mistakenly added to the snippet.

Comment: @DarkoRomanov If it works inside the DOM ready handler but not the click event handler the issue isn't that it hasn't been loaded yet.

Comment: I thought the plugin was loaded externally. At this point a Fiddle would be very useful.

Comment: You should also verify that you don't have another jQuery inclusion after the declaration of $.fn.coreFrame that would reset all plugins declared previously.

Comment: @ Darko Romanov I have tried to regenerate it in the fiddle. Sorry but I couldn't.

Comment: FYI

I found a solution. 

(function($){

Do the codings.

})(jquery);